# Copy functionality in iOS by using UIPasteboard

Tags: iphone, uipasteboard

```
 NSString *copyStringverse = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[textview.text]];
 UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
 [pb setString:copyStringverse];
```

I'm using above code for copying contents in `textview`, but I want to copy contents in a cell of the table. How to do this?

Comment: This gave me the perfect solution to copy/pasting from my app - regardless of the fact that you needed something slightly different. cheers!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Well you don't say exactly how you have your table view cell set up, but if it's just text inside your table view it could be as easy as:

```
// provided you actually have your table view cell
NSString *copyStringverse = yourSelectedOrClickedTableViewCell.textLabel.text;
UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pb setString:copyStringverse];
```

Comment: haii thanks for your reply,what s yourSelectedOrClickedTableViewCell ?table name?

Comment: @Micheal Dautermann i need to put it inside the butytonclick,so the text label shows eror

Comment: `yourSelectedOrClickedTableViewCell` is a `UITableViewCell`. You have to figure out which cell is being clicked.  I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, so I don't know how you would invoke the copying and I couldn't come up with a better code sample.

Answer (score 27):

```
[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string = @"Copy me!";
```

Answer (score 15):

For Swift 3.x

```
UIPasteboard.general.string = "String to copy"
```

Answer (score 4):

For Swift 2.1+:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! UITableViewCell // change this to your custom cell if you use one
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = cell.textLabel.text
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift2.2

```
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = tableViewCell.textLabel.text
```

By using this you can directly set the value to `UIPasteboard`.

Comment: Keep in mind that in Swift 3 "generalPasteboard()" doesn't exist anymore. User general instead.