# Copy content of UILabel to clipboard

Tags: ios, uilabel, clipboard

I subclasses UILabel to create a copiable label with this project.
[UILabel clipboard](https://github.com/zoul/UILabel-Clipboard-Sample)

This is the code it has:

```
- (void) copy: (id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"Copy handler, label: “%@”.", self.text);
}

- (BOOL) canPerformAction: (SEL) action withSender: (id) sender
{
return (action == @selector(copy:));
}

- (void) handleTap: (UIGestureRecognizer*) recognizer
{
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    [menu setTargetRect:self.frame inView:self.superview];
    [menu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
}

- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

And the NSLog logs exactly the content I want to copy inside the label, however, the content is not copied to the clipboard.

Any idea?

And how to copy image?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869569/copy-functionality-in-ios-by-using-uipasteboard

Comment: I'm sure an image is almost identical. Look at the NSPasteboard class

Comment: @MillieSmith - using UIKit so I think you mean `UIPasteboard` - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant :). Thanks @Adam.